# Problems passing test suite from Google Home

Tags: google-smart-home, test-suite

I have a google action that controls some devices and after the last updaste, I wasn't able to pass the suite test to push the release to production. The actions had passed before and the code of the SYNC, QUERY and EXECUTE haven't changed. I've seen that while testing I'm not recieving any request to my server, It is possible that is testing another version ?

https://developers.home.google.com/tools/test-suite

We've modified the response with the format expected from Google adjunted below and still giving the same errors.

https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/intents/query

I've seen that Conversational Actions got deprecated this year, but I don't know if applies to me as the terminology that I have seen from Google talking about the subject isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

There can a be bunch of reasons for you not being able to pass the suite test to push the release to production.

- Can you check and verify if the access token and refresh tokens for your project are valid and not expired ?
- Can you also once verify if you are passing the correct project ID ?

For your concern about whether your project is a conversational actions project or a smart home project can be verified through [Actions on Google](https://console.actions.google.com/) console. Under the list of projects for your account you can see as to what kind of project you are working.